# Does findOneAndUpdate perform updates atomically? (As findAndModify is not available in Java MongoDB async driver)

Tags: mongodb, mongo-java-driver

I am using MongoDB's Java Async Driver version 3.6, I don't see a `findAndModify` implemented as part of `MongoCollection` Class (am I mistaken?), the closest thing is `findOneAndUpdate` can someone confirm that this operation will be performed atomically?

I understand how concurrent updates happen. The question is very specific are atomic ( read+write) guarantees atomic for the findOneAndUpdate api or not. It is not the same as asking how to use findAndmodify.

Answer (score 3):

According to these [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/write-operations-atomicity/) , single write transactions are atomic.  So with findOneAndUpdate, this would indeed be atomic.  If you are doing batch writes or updates for example, then each action individually is atomic but not all of the actions as a whole.

Comment: thanks I did read that bit but I couldn't infer from that, that the (search + write) itself will be atomic.

Comment: @amritanshu So is (search + write) atomic?
Asking you since you have not accepted the answer.

Comment: I dont know anymore I had thought of looking up the source or asking the developer list. I don't agree with the inference drawn from the referred document.